flextable: I want to remove second level header
I am pretty new to R and trying to format a flextable. I would like to remove the second level header altogether (blue arrow).

I would like to remove the second level of the header. I've created the new header with the merged columns I want.
I have tried removing the header first then creating my new one but the formating goes.
Thanks for your help!
The code I have to create my table.
section_11_table <- flextable(section_11)
columns_to_format <- c("Less than 6 months %", "Between 6 months to a year %", "Between 1 and 2 years %", "More than 2 years %", "Duration not available %")
section_11_table <- colformat_double(section_11_table, j = columns_to_format, big.mark = ",", digits = 1, suffix = "%")

section_11_table <- add_header_row(
  section_11_table,
  values = c("Local Authority Name", "Less than 6 months",
             "Between 6 months to a year",
             "Between 1 and 2 years",
             "More than 2 years",
             "Duration not available",
             "Total assessments completed"),
  colwidths = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1)
)

section_11_table <- set_header_labels(
  section_11_table,
  "Local Authority (LA) Name" = "",
  "Less than 6 months" = "Count",
  "Less than 6 months %" = "%",
  "Between 6 months to a year" = "Count",
  "Between 6 months to a year %" = "%",
  "Between 1 and 2 years" = "Count",
  "Between 1 and 2 years %" = "%",
  "More than 2 years" = "Count",
  "More than 2 years %" = "%",
  "Duration not available" = "Count",
  "Duration not available %" = "%",
  "Total assessments completed" = ""
)



section_11_table <- theme_vanilla(section_11_table) # Apply a theme
section_11_table <- autofit(section_11_table) # Automatically adjust column widths
section_11_table <- align(section_11_table, i = 1, j = NULL, align = "center", part = "header") 
section_11_table <- bold(section_11_table, i = 2, bold = TRUE) # make the total row bold

section_11_table


Please share your dataset section_11  so that we can help.

Like @David Gohel, we would need example data, such as posting the output of dput(section_11). Have you tried removing the ='s from set_header_labels()?

https://gist.github.com/carmelh/fe2386009f0c098c8248e64b6166dda6
this is an example of the dataset i'm working with

Before add_header_row delete the old header:
section_11_table = delete_part(section_11_table, part = "header")

Hope it works.

Thank you! I thought I tried something like this but it removed the formatting but maybe I had it in the wrong place.
